# XNA Content Directory Iteration

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, xna, xna-4.0

Are there any objects or functions that can iterate through the files in a set directory in XNA Content?

I have a set of images in a directory in my game's content, but as the project goes on, I will be adding more. However, I don't want to have to go and add a line of code every time I add a new image, it would be much better if I was able to just iterate through every file in the directory and load them into an array. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this handy extension method

```
public static class Extension Methods
{
        public static List<T> LoadContentFolder<T>(this ContentManager contentManager, string contentFolder)
        {
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(contentManager.RootDirectory + "/" + contentFolder);
            if (!dir.Exists)
                throw new DirectoryNotFoundException();
            List<T> result = new List<T>();

            FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles("*.*");
            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            {
                result.Add(contentManager.Load<T>(contentFolder + "/" + file.Name.Split('.')[0]));
            }
            return result;
        }
}
```

Remove the "this" keyword from the constuctor if you dont want to extend the class. You can use it like so:

```
Dictionary<string,Texture2D> folderContent = Content.LoadContentFolder<Texture2D>("FolderName");
```

FolderName is just a subfolder within your content folder

And access by doing `folderContent["MyAssetName"]`

Comment: Works fine for me, even with ClickOnce deployment. Set your content folder to "Content" and specify a folder, it will be copied even when distibuted.

Comment: I double checked using a friend's computer and have found that this does in fact work. I also found it works with streamreaders/streamwriters, but the data being accessed is in XNB format because XNA converts all files given to it into XNB format before condensing them into the application. The directory thing most assuredly works though.

Answer (score 1):

Not in XNA 4.0. MS decided to obscure some methods that made this possible in XNA 3.1. Here's an example project showing a workaround for you to review -- it winds up building a file list during the build process which is a kludge, but it gets you to where you want, I think.

[Content Manifest Extension Sample](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/sample/contentmanifestextensions)